# The ListView 'Luser' raised event ItemDeleting which wasn't handled

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms

I want to delete record from front end. But when i run my code I face this error.

> The ListView 'Luser' raised event ItemDeleting which wasn't handled

Below is the my attempt.

```
<td class="pr-0 text-left">
    <a href='<%# Eval("URL")%>' class="btn btn-icon btn-light btn-hover-primary btn-sm">
        <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-md svg-icon-primary">
            <!--begin::Svg Icon | path:assets/media/svg/icons/Communication/Write.svg-->
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1">
                <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                    <rect x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" />
                    <path d="M12.2674799,18.2323597 L12.0084872,5.45852451 C12.0004303,5.06114792 12.1504154,4.6768183 12.4255037,4.38993949 L15.0030167,1.70195304 L17.5910752,4.40093695 C17.8599071,4.6812911 18.0095067,5.05499603 18.0083938,5.44341307 L17.9718262,18.2062508 C17.9694575,19.0329966 17.2985816,19.701953 16.4718324,19.701953 L13.7671717,19.701953 C12.9505952,19.701953 12.2840328,19.0487684 12.2674799,18.2323597 Z" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" transform="translate(14.701953, 10.701953) rotate(-135.000000) translate(-14.701953, -10.701953)" />
                    <path d="M12.9,2 C13.4522847,2 13.9,2.44771525 13.9,3 C13.9,3.55228475 13.4522847,4 12.9,4 L6,4 C4.8954305,4 4,4.8954305 4,6 L4,18 C4,19.1045695 4.8954305,20 6,20 L18,20 C19.1045695,20 20,19.1045695 20,18 L20,13 C20,12.4477153 20.4477153,12 21,12 C21.5522847,12 22,12.4477153 22,13 L22,18 C22,20.209139 20.209139,22 18,22 L6,22 C3.790861,22 2,20.209139 2,18 L2,6 C2,3.790861 3.790861,2 6,2 L12.9,2 Z" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" opacity="0.3" />
                </g>
            </svg>
            <!--end::Svg Icon-->
        </span>
    </a>
    </td>
    <td><%#Eval("User_Name")%></td>
    <td><%#Eval("User_Email")%></td>
    <td><%#Eval("Role_Id")%></td>
    <td class="pr-0 text-left" >
    <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("User_Id")%>' CommandName="Delete" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
</td>
```

Here is the code from c#

```
protected void Luser_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        LinkButton abc = e.Item.FindControl("DeleteButton") as LinkButton;
        User ue = db.Users.Where(x => x.User_Id.ToString() == abc.CommandArgument).First();
        ue.Delete_record = "Yes";
        db.SubmitChanges();

        preload();

        StMsg("Yes", "Record deleted succesfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that you've posted enough code as you don't show any code for `ListView`. Why not add `OnClick` to `<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" ... OnClick="DeleteButton">` . Then, `protected void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (DeleteButton.CommandName == "Delete") {  //ToDo: add desired code } }`

Comment: Either drop in a blank delete code stub, or use your OWN custom name say like "mydelete" for the command name.

Comment: Thank you very much. It resolved my problem.